# Ubuntu LTS buggy display

Tags: 14.04, display, bug-reporting

I had searched around but find nothing useful. My (don't know to say right) "display" act weirdly. Please see image below. This happens randomly, approximate on an hour interval.

[image: link]

I don't know why this happens, so if you know anything please help me.